# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have problem with djanggo 1.7 and i use python 2.7

this code in models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description     = models.TextField()
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):

    author          = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    tag             = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text            = models.TextField()
    created_date    = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
)
```

i am succesfully makemigrations but when i am try /manage.py migrate i am getting error like this

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

can you help me solve this provlem?

Comment: can you post your urls.py?

Comment: i already post my urls.py in above

Comment: I think that it would better if you will include the detailed stacktrace into your question.Believe me this can help us to answer you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)` try `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: You should provide the complete call trace if you have it

Comment: can you delete or rename the migrations folder and try migrating from makemigrations?

Comment: you mean delete migration? i am not understand